# Problem with Exception caught without argument

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Encountered a strange problem with this event, event wrapper and handler:

```
public delegate void StatusUpdateHandler(string message, Exception exc, SeverityLevel severity);

public event StatusUpdateHandler StatusUpdate;

private void FireStatusUpdate(string message)
{
    if (this.StatusUpdate != null)
        this.StatusUpdate(message, null, SeverityLevel.None);
}

void scanDocProcessor_StatusUpdate(string message, Exception exc, SeverityLevel severity)
{
    try
    {
        if (exc != null)
        {
            if (severity >= setSevLevel)
                this._logger.Log(message + Environment.NewLine + exc.ToString(), LogEntryType.Emergency, "OCR Submission Processor Status Update", true);
            else
                this._logger.Log(message + Environment.NewLine + exc.ToString(), LogEntryType.Error, "OCR Submission Processor Status Update", false);
        }
        else if (severity >= setSevLevel)
        {
            this._logger.Log(message, LogEntryType.Info, "OCR Submission Processor Status Update", true, true);
        }
        else
            this._logger.Log(message, LogEntryType.Info, "OCR Submission Processor Status Update", false);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Russia OCR Submission Processor", "Could not log status update event: " + exc.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }
}
```

For a period of a few minutes, the _logger stopped logging messages and instead I received these messages in the event log:

> Could not log status update event: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at ScannedService.scanDocProcessor_StatusUpdate(String message, Exception exc, SeverityLevel severity)
>      at ScannedService.Processor.FireStatusUpdate(String message)
>      at ScannedService.Processor.ProcessQueue(Object Object)

I'm confused how the Event log could get such a stack trace when it should be writing exc.ToString().  I looked at the IL for the scanDocProcessor_StatusUpdate method is not initializing an Exception object.  Beyond that I don't know how a nullreferenceexception is getting thrown. When the Log method does catch an exception it swallows it or re-throws it with "throw;".  The message parameter is never null and SeverityLevel is an enumeration.

Comment: Never catch `Exception` unless you intend to exit the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are throwing an exception in one of the `else` conditions where `ecx` is null. In the `catch` block, you are assuming that `ecx` is not null, which generates *another* exception that hides your original one.

You can make your log statement null-safe with the following:

```
EventLog.WriteEntry("Russia OCR Submission Processor", 
    String.Format("Could not log status update event: {0}", exc), EventLogEntryType.Information);
```